# Регулярное выражение для выборки id из ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток, я формирую такую вот ссылку на новости у себя на сайте. После /p/ идёт id новости (он может иметь как 2 числа так и 5) по которому я делаю потом выборку из БД в контролере и открываю новость во вьюшке.

http://localhost/news/p/**31260**o-v_tsentre_feodosii_proydet_nedelnaya_yarmarka.html

После
**id** идет буква либо **o** либо **k**, они указывают из какой БД делать выборку. Я так понял обычным **substr** или **str_replace** тут не обойтись. 
Нужно регулярное выражение (с ними у меня большая беда), чтобы отсеять строку от последнего слеша **"/"** до тире **"-"** и отделить id от буквы.

Если кто-то может подсказать хотя-бы примерно, как должно выглядеть такое рег. выражение, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Самое простое вот так `([\d]+(o|k))`. Возвратит число с буквой. В вашем примере: 31260o

Comment: @DemianShumilov `'~(?<=/)(\d{2,5})([ok])~'`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно воздержаться от регулярок, я предпочитаю так и сделать

```
$res =  explode('-', end(explode('/', $str)))[0];
echo substr($res,-1) . '  ' . substr($res,0,-1);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/937134)

Comment: Спасибо, интересный вариант.

Comment: В таком случае, его и применю, Вы правы

Answer (score 1):

```
/news\/p\/(\d{2}|\d{5})(o|k)/
```

В первой группе ловите число из 2 или 5 цифр. Во второй группе букву **o** или **k**.

Тест https://regex101.com/r/abStCM/1

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что нужно